# Korean Characters Not Working simplexml_load_file

Tags: php, simplexml

well currently I'm loading the youtube rss feed using

simplexml_load_file

The problem I've run into is that it's not returning anything when I use korean characters in the url. The youtube url works just fine if you type it in the browser, but if you run it through the function nothing.

and example url is

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=%EB%95%8C%EB%B6%80%ED%84%B0&orderby=viewCount&start-index=1&max-results=10
```

loads just fine if you put it in your browser but simplexml_load_file returns nothing.

Thanks

Comment: This works for me.  What is the exact code you're using?

Comment: Make sure that your php file is encoded as UTF-8 without BOM and that encoding of your html is UTF-8 as well (<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">). I can defo load that url using simplexml_load_file and I can see Korean characters just fine in the browser when running print_r.

Comment: i have my encoding as utf-8 first then ISO-2022-KR after in order to display the korean characters.

Comment: @Belgin Fish, what is the output from `var_dump(simplexml_load_file('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=%EB%95%8C%EB%B6%80%ED%84%B0&orderby=viewCount&start-index=1&max-results=10'));`

Comment: You don't need to set ISO-2022-KR  to display Korean characters. That's the whole purpose of UTF-8 - to have one universal encoding.

Comment: does it work from the command line? i.e. `$ php -r "var_dump..."`

Comment: @thetaiko, Belgin Fish -> when I run the var_dump line on my php server it outputs the correct data.  SO might be scrambling the URL a bit so make sure to copy that which is in the question.